# Excel IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

I think my logic is wrong?, please help.

Score Grade: 80 A+, 70 A, 50 C, 40 F, 0-39 FAIL

```
=IF(B26=79,"A+",IF(B26>=69,"A",IF(B26>=49,"C",IF(B26=40,"A","F"))))
```

Comment: Remove the last `IF` and just put `F` there, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Using `INDEX`, `MATCH` to avoid nested `IF` statements, paste below to `B2`:

```
=INDEX({"-","Fail","F","C","A","A+","-"},MATCH(A2,{-10,0,40,50,70,80,101,110}))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would not be able to map 72 to A, for example.

Comment: yes it would  ,   using  0 or 1 as the last parameter sets weather or not to use exact match

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur just tested `72` maps to `A`. Could you explain why it wouldn't have matched?

Comment: Oh never used 0 there ans never used match with a numeric key. That's why I thought it wouldn't work. Hey, thanks for this trick.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution for this kind of issue is `VLOOKUP`.  The array can either be embedded in the formula, or in some other cell reference.

e.g:

```
=VLOOKUP(B26,{0,"FAIL";40,"F";50,"C";70,"A";80,"A+"},2)
```

or, set up a table someplace.  You can name it GradeTable, in, let us say F1:G5.

[image: GradeTable]

Then Use:

```
=VLOOKUP(B26,GradeTable,2)
```